# In Javascript a dictionary comprehension, or an Object `map`

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I need to generate a couple of objects from lists in Javascript. In Python, I'd write this:

```
{key_maker(x): val_maker(x) for x in a_list}
```

Another way to ask is does there exist something like `jQuery.map()` which aggregates objects? Here's my guess (doesn't work):

```
var result = {}
$.map(a_list, function(x) {
    $.extend(result, {key_maker(x): val_maker(x)})
})
```

Comment: FYI, your `$.extend` version won't work. Property identifiers in object literal notation can't be the result of an expression. This code will fail... `{key_maker(x): val_maker(x)}`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming `a_list` is an Array, the closest would probably be to use `.reduce()`.

```js
var result = a_list.reduce(function(obj, x) {
    obj[key_maker(x)] = val_maker(x);
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Array comprehensions are likely coming in a future version of JavaScript.

---

You can patch non ES5 compliant implementations with the [compatibility patch from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility).

---

If `a_list` is not an Array, but a plain object, you can use `Object.keys()` to perform the same operation.

```js
var result = Object.keys(a_list).reduce(function(obj, x) {
    obj[key_maker(a_list[x])] = val_maker(a_list[x]);
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: If using a version of JS that doesn't have `reduce`, I don't think jQuery ever added it, either.  But underscore has it.

Comment: @MarkReed: True. I updated with a link to the MDN compatibility patch.

Comment: jQuery does not have reduce (yet). You can find some implementations in its trac here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1886

Comment: Using underscore or lodash, it would be: `_.reduce(a_list, function(obj, x){ ... }, {});`

Comment: A slightly shorter version using arrow notation and the comma operator: `a_list.reduce((o, x) => (o[key_maker(x)] = val_maker(x), o), {})`

Answer (score 75):

Here's a version that doesn't use reduce:

```
Object.fromEntries( a_list.map( x => [key_maker(x), value_maker(x)]) );
```

[Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is basically the same as [_.fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#fromPairs) in Lodash.  This feels the most like the Python dict comprehension to me.

Comment: It's the closer we can get to the comprehension without special syntax IMO, though as of Jan 2019 it's still a proposal and not implemented in NodeJS.

Comment: I think this is quite dict comprehension-like, and could probably be the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but the answer has changed slightly in new versions of Javascript. With ES2015 (ES6) you can achieve a one-liner object comprehension like this:

```
a_list.reduce((obj, x) => Object.assign(obj, { [key_maker(x)]: value_maker(x) }), {})
```

Answer (score 6):

[ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) introduced `Map` for an *OrderedDict*.  A Map comprehension might look like:

```
Map( Array.map(function(o){return[ key_maker(o), val_maker(o) ]}))
```

Example:

```
> a_list = [ {x:1}, {x:2}, {x:3} ]
< [ Object, Object, Object ]
>
> let dict = new Map(a_list.map(function(o){return[ o.x, o.x**2 ]}))
< Map[3]
< 0 : {1 => 1}
< 1 : {2 => 4}
< 2 : {3 => 9}
>
> dict.get(2)
< 4
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this, using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#fromPairs):

`var result = _.fromPairs(a_list.map(x => [key_maker(x), value_maker(x)]));`

Answer (score 4):

A shorter ES6 version would be:

```
a_list.reduce((obj, x) => (obj[key_maker(x)] = val_maker(x), obj),{})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest version of typescript and I use

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, ...];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(val, idx) => [func1(val), func2(val)]))
// python equivalent: {func1(x): func2(x) for x in a_list}
```