# Construct Object From Two Arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two lists that I want to combine as key value pairs:

```
keys = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016'];

values = ['janData', 'febData', 'marData'];
```

The desired outcome I want is:

```
dataMap = {
    'Jan 2016': 'janData',
    'Feb 2016': 'febData',
    'Mar 2016': 'marData'
};
```

I looked at [In Javascript a dictionary comprehension, or an Object `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068247/in-javascript-a-dictionary-comprehension-or-an-object-map) and saw there are ways to build an object using `.reduce()` or `assign()` given an existing array. However I couldn't figure out how to adapt those methods when I have *two* arrays.

**Question:** How can I construct my `dataMap` object from two existing arrays?

It seems object comprehensions have gotten some updates in recent years. `assign()` seems to be pretty new, but maybe it's not the best tool for my task. Also, I'm using native javascript only.

Comment: I'd imagine using reduce something like this: ```var dataMap = keys.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => { accumulator[currentValue] = values[currentIndex] }, {})```

Comment: You should really try lodash for stuff like this: `_.fromPairs(_.zip(keys, values))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function `forEach`.

```js
var keys = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016'];
var values = ['janData', 'febData', 'marData'];

let result = {};
keys.forEach((k, i) => result[k] = values[i]);

console.log(result);
```

**You can initialize a `Map` object:**

*Map constructor*

> An Array or other iterable object whose elements are key-value pairs (arrays with two elements, e.g. `[[ 1, 'one' ],[ 2, 'two' ]]`). Each key-value pair is added to the new Map; null values are treated as undefined.

```js
var keys = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016'];
var values = ['janData', 'febData', 'marData'];

let result = new Map(keys.map((k, i) => [[k], values[i]]));

for (let key of result.keys()) {
  console.log(`${key} = ${result.get(key)}`);
}
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Class Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with **Array**'s `forEach()`:

```js
var keys = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016'];
var values = ['janData', 'febData', 'marData'];
var dataMap = {};
keys.forEach(function(k, i){
  dataMap[k] = values[i];
})

console.log(dataMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let dataMap = {}

for (let month in keys) {
    const _key = keys[month]
    dataMap[_key] = values[month]
}
```

This answer depends on your arrays being in the "same" order

Answer (score 1):

I know there are already a lot of really good answers on here, but here is another approach that you could take if you want a more "functional programming" approach:

```js
const keys = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016'];
const values = ['janData', 'febData', 'marData'];
const dataMap = keys.map((key, i) => ({
    [key]: values[i]
  }))
  .reduce((key, val) => Object.assign({}, key, val), {});
```