# How to write python lambda with multiple lines?

Tags: python, lambda

In python, how can you write a lambda function taking multiple lines. I tried

```
d = lambda x: if x:
                 return 1
              else 
                 return 2
```

but I am getting errors...

Comment: If you are giving it a name, just use the proper `def` statement.

Comment: This is one of the two worst things in python: the other being the lack of ability to chain collections processing in any sane/readable manner.  The workaround hack is the `for comprehensions: but those only are readable to two levels

Comment: I found a nice workaround by simplying re-using `def` with the same name repeatedly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77629850/1599699 Very powerful, flexible, and simple. Next best thing for this purpose.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use `def` instead.

```
def d(x):
    if x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

All python functions are first order objects (they can be passed as arguments), `lambda` is just a convenient way to make short ones. In general, you are better off using a normal function definition if it becomes anything beyond one line of simple code.

Even then, in fact, if you are assigning it to a name, I would always use `def` over `lambda`. `lambda` is really only a good idea when defining short `key` functions, for use with `sorted()`, for example, as they can be placed inline into the function call.

Note that, in your case, a ternary operator would do the job (`lambda x: 1 if x else 2`), but I'm presuming this is a simplified case.

(As a code golf note, this could also be done in less code as `lambda x: bool(x)+1` - of course, that's highly unreadable and a bad idea.)

Comment: For the unreadable golf contest, I like better `-~bool(x)`, but have the same char count :)

Comment: @JBernardo Here was me thinking that was as unreadable as it was going to get. Hats off to you sir.

Comment: `def` can not be inline with the logic but has to reside separately.  It breaks the flow of reading the code.  But this is what we deal with in python.

Answer (score 47):

`lambda` construct in Python is [limited to an expression only](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda), no statements are allowed

While keeping the above mentioned constraint, you can write an expression with multiple lines using backslash char, of course:

```
>>> fn = lambda x: 1 if x \
                     else 2
>>> fn(True)
>>> 1
>>> fn(False)
>>> 2
```

Answer (score -10):

Here's a correct version of what you are trying to do:

```
d = lambda x: 1 if x else 2
```

But I am not sure why you want to do that.

Comment: This does not answer to the question that was asked in the title.