# How do I do multiple things inside one lambda function?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I want to do multiple things inside one lambda function.

Just for a small example if I want to do addition, subtraction, and multiplication in one function, how do I do that?

I tried to use code like this just to see if it would work and it didn't:

```
a = 1
b = 2
myFunction = lambda a, b: a + b, b - a, a * b
print(myFunction(a, b))
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Don't use a lambda if you are going to give it a name anyway

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843777/how-to-write-python-lambda-with-multiple-lines

Comment: Sidenote: [named lambdas are bad practice](/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a slight syntax issue around a `lambda` returning a tuple.

Use this syntax:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
myFunction = lambda a, b: (a + b, b - a, a * b)
print(myFunction(a, b))
```

Comment: There is no syntax issue with `lambda` (or at all), it just makes `myFunction` a tuple (just like it would in any other case)

Comment: The parenthesis are needed here because Python has no idea if the intention is `lambda a, b: a + b, b - a, a * b`, `lambda a, b: (a + b, b - a), a * b` or `lambda a, b: (a + b, b - a, a * b)`

Comment: @DeepSpace: Ok, so what is the name of the issue that requires the programmer to use parentheses to indicate that the lambda should return a `tuple`?

Comment: @DeepSpace is right, the issue is with the grouping. When you do `myfunction = lambda x:x, x`, this creates a tuple that contains the function in the first item and x as the second element. Thus myfunction is a tuple containing a function, not a function.

Comment: @mozway: Yes, Is there a reason for that interpretation? Does it have a name?

Comment: @quamrana: this is called [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

You can group those operations in a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

```
a = 1
b = 2
myFunction = lambda a, b: (a + b, b - a, a * b)
myFunction(a, b)
```

output:

```
(3, 1, 2)
```

NB. The mistake in you code is that myFunction was a tuple containing your lambda as first element, not a function.