# Why Python does not allow statements in the local scope of a lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda, scope, expression

I've found this page:

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-lambda-forms-contain-statements.htm

Nevertheless, it's not so clear the reason why. Lambdas are powerful, and, in my mind, they would be much more if it was possible to use statements/assignments inside their scope.

For example:

```
y = 0
f = lambda x: y = 5, x+y # Statements first, expression later.
print f(5) # 10
```

Someone must have considered this, and there must be a reason why it's not implemented (Perhaps to avoid using them too much instead of a trivial def?).

Comment: Why not `lambda x: x + 5`? Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233448/no-multiline-lambda-in-python-why-not

Comment: @JesseMu: Although I wouldn't say an exact duplicate, the second answer there is, what I believe the OP is looking for.

Comment: Because it makes readability worse. Also giving names to anonymous functions kinda defeats the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one needs to understand that the `lambda` construct creates an *expression* that evaluates to the created function. This is very different from a `def`, which is a statement, and works by side effect of binding the created function to the specified name. For `lambda` to be useful at all, it **must** be an expression, otherwise you couldn't nest it in other expressions.

As the linked FAQ explains, no other Python expression is allowed to nest statements. This is because the core syntactic tradeoffs of the Python language preclude such possibility, as [persuasively argued by Guido](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=147358). Since there is a very easy workaround, i.e. using a `def`, it was deemed not worthwhile to warp the syntax of the language to accomodate statements in `lambda`.

Also note that `lambda` is not the only place in the language that requires an expression. You can't put a statement in the test of an `if` or `while`, nor in the expression required by the `for` statement. Yet this is considered a good thing - if you need statements there, simply extract them into a function and call it. Exactly the same applies to `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the different between:

```
f = lambda x: y = 5; x+y
```

and

```
def f(x):
    y = 5
    return x+y
```

?

The later is more readable, it has a consistent syntax and the only code you have to write more, than with your lambda-definition is the `return`. So there is no need in what you suggest but only more complicated rules.