# Python recursion challenge

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

I am currently in an introduction to Python and computational theory class, and there was recently a difficult question on the midterm that I simply was not able to solve. It involves writing code for a program that adds numbers. I believe the question is supposed to use recursion. I don't remember how exactly the question was worded, but here is the basic idea.

Implement the `multiadder(n)` function, which takes in a nonnegative integer `n` and adds `n` arbitrary values together. Each value to be added must be written as a separate call. For example:

```
>>> multi_three = multiadder(3)
>>> multi_three(1)(2)(3)
6

>>> multiadder(5)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
15
```

The code must be written by filling in the blanks.

```
def multiadder(n):
    assert n > 0
    if _________________________ :
        return _________________________
    else:
        return _________________________
```

The topics we have covered in class are higher order functions, recursion, lambdas, and control statements. We are not allowed to use data structure like lists and sets, nor are we allowed to import anything.

Someone please help. It's the only problem I couldn't get on the test!

Comment: It's easy if you're allowed to add a second parameter with a default value to `multiadder`. Since you say that you don't remember the exact question, are you sure you have the blanks correct here?

Comment: I'm really not sure if it's possible given structure to be filled. You need to keep track of both accumulator state and level state (to known when to stop returning callables and return accumulated value) and you have only one variable to use, `n`.

Comment: So you're just to add consecutive numbers as in your example or arbitrary integers?

Comment: The adding numbers are arbitrary integers. The exact wording of the question I don't remember, but the code structure I know for sure is correct. It is possible that the professor made a mistake, but it would be his first ever mistake on a test that I know of.

Comment: How is this not an example of using Stack Overflow as a code-writing service?

Comment: I feel like the professor would rather be using Haskell than Python for this course.

Comment: This isn't to broad. And the answer is short.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
def multiadder(n):
  assert n > 0
  if n == 1:
    return lambda t: t
  else:
    return lambda a: lambda b: multiadder(n-1)(a+b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(multiadder(5)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5))
```

For `n == 1`, the result must be a function returning the input.

For `n > 1`, wrap the result of `n-1`, by adding input.

This also works for concatenating strings, and other accumulating operations:

```
>>> multiadder(3)('p')('q')('r')
pqr
```

Comment: If I run this for `multiadder(1)(2)(3)` I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: @AnthonyBlackshaw That behaviour is expected. `multiadder(2)(2)(3)` is what you should do

Comment: @MosesKoledoye sorry you're correct I miss read the initial example.

Comment: the first argument is the number of consecutive calls, try: `multiadder(3)(1)(2)(3)`

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this, but it is almost unreadable. I hope the explanations are helpful:

```
def multiadder(n):
    assert n > 0
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (lambda f: lambda i, n, sm: f(f, i, n, sm))(
                    lambda rec, i, n, sm: sm+i if n == 0 else lambda j: rec(rec, j, n-1, sm+i)
                )(0, n, 0)
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dbix).

#### How it works

The return value consists of three major parts:

```
(lambda f: lambda i, n, sm: f(f, i, n, sm))
```

In short, this function assigns a name to a function, so it can be called recursively. In more detail: 
It takes a function `f` that must itself accept 4 arguments, of which the first should be a self-reference. 
The function that is returned here takes the three other arguments, and returns the recursive call of `f`.

Part two is the real core:

```
(lambda rec, i, n, sm: sm+i if n == 0 else lambda j: rec(rec, j, n-1, sm+i))
```

This is passed as argument to the first function above, making recursion possible.
This function takes the 4 arguments mentioned above, and applies the specific logic:

- `i` is the number that must be added
- `n` is the number of values still expected after this one
- `sm` is the so far accumulated sum (excluding `i`)

Depending on whether more values are expected this function returns the final result (`sm+i`) or 
a function with one argument that will do the same as described here (recursion) with decreased `n`, and adapted sum.

Finally, the initial values are passed to the above:

```
(0, n, 0)
```

Meaning, we start with number 0 (dummy), `n` expected values, and a current sum of 0.

#### Note

As the recursion in the above code does not involve a call to `multiladder`, and the assertion really excludes the `if` condition to be true, we can do without that `if...else`:

```
def multiadder(n):
    assert n > 0
    return (lambda f: lambda i, n, sm: f(f, i, n, sm))(
                lambda rec, i, n, sm: sm+i if n == 0 else lambda j: rec(rec, j, n-1, sm+i)
            )(0, n, 0)
```

Comment: Looks like Church arithmetic, kind of

Comment: If `assert n > 0` then `if n == 0: return 0` will never be executed, won't it?

Comment: Indeed, @boardrider, I wrote about that in my answer near the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could also define an internal auxiliary function (`loop`) which keeps track of the sum state (`acc`) as the counter state (`n`) decrements

```
def multiadder(n):
  def loop(acc,n):
    if n == 0:
      return acc
    else:
      return lambda x: loop(acc+x, n-1)
  return loop(0,n)

print(multiadder(3)(1)(2)(3)) # 6
print(multiadder(5)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)) # 15
```

It's not nearly as elegant as DarkKnight's answer, but it might be easier for a beginner to conceptualize. In fact, this pattern is so useful and versatile that I use it to define almost all of my recursive procedures.

```
def some_recursive_func:
  def loop(...state_parameters):
    if base_condition:
      return answer
    else:
      return loop(...updated_state_variables)
  return loop(...initial_state_variables)
```

The only adaptation we made to this pattern is wrapping the recursive branch of the `if` expression in in `lambda x: ...` – this is because `multiadd` is meant to return functions until `n` returned functions have been applied.

---

One more, just for fun using the legendary [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus). This probably doesn't meet the criteria provided by your instructor, but it's cool to see it nonetheless. [Multiline lambdas in python are not really a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233448/no-multiline-lambda-in-python-why-not) so readability suffers a little bit.

```
U = lambda f: f(f)
Y = U (lambda h: lambda f: f (lambda x: h (h) (f) (x)))

multiadder = Y (lambda f: lambda acc: lambda n:
  acc if n == 0 else lambda x: f (acc+x) (n-1)
) (0)

print(multiadder(3)(1)(2)(3)) # 6
print(multiadder(5)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)) # 15
```

Or you could still have defined `multiadder` using `def` syntax if you wanted

```
def multiadder(n):
  return Y (lambda f: lambda acc: lambda n:
    acc if n == 0 else lambda x: f (acc+x) (n-1)
  ) (0) (n)
```

It works the same way.

I highly encourage you to trace the evaluation step-by-step to understand how it works. There are some tremendous insights to be gained in understanding these higher-order functions.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit more on your answer? It seems like there is something valuable here but I haven't figured it out yet. (Beginner here)

Comment: @DanielG sure, I'd be happy to help. Is there a particular section which is confusing? Maybe let me know what parts you understand and I can try to elaborate on the rest

Comment: No, the answer is not confusing. I just don't quite see where the nesting is coming from. In DarkKnight's answer we have two lambdas in the `else` branch, so at each recursion the nesting increases.

Comment: Yes the locally defined function is something we learned in class and used in many places on the test. I would have done exactly this if possible.

Comment: @DanielG the "trick" to DarkKnight's answer is she/he applies two functions under the double lambda, so the nesting level never increases beyond a 2 deep.

Answer (score -2):

At first it seemed liked multiadder needed two inputs for this to work, but the answer is quite straightforward. I wouldn't think an "Introduction to Python" class would need lamba functions and so on.

This is final answer:

```
def multiadder(n):
    assert n > 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n + multiadder(n - 1)
```

The graph below explains how it works for n = 4:

```
multiadder(4)
     |
 return 4 + multiadder(3)
                  |
               return 3 + multiadder(2) 
                               |
                            return 2 + multiadder(1)
                                             |
                                         return 1
```

So the final result for n = 4 ends up being 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10.

Comment: I think you've misread the problem description. It's not supposed to add up the first `n` numbers, but the specific `n` numbers provided in the chained function calls.

Comment: Oh yes you're right. My answer is just a cumulative sum... I'll leave it anyway. Thanks for point this out Blckknght