# Print the first n numbers of the fibonacci sequence in one expression

Tags: python, recursion, lambda, fibonacci, lambda-calculus

So I've been messing around with Python a bit lately and I'm trying to find a way to output the nth number of the fibonacci sequence in a single expression. This is the code that I've written so far:

```
(lambda f: f if f<2 else (f-1)+(f-2))(n)
# n == 1 -> 1
# n == 2 -> 1
# n == 3 -> 3
# n == 4 -> 5
# n == 5 -> 7
....
```

However, as I commented above this simply outputs a set of odd numbers. I'm confused as to why this is happening because if I am to re-write this as a named lambda function, it would look something like this:

```
f = lambda n: n if n<2 else f(f-1)+f(f-2)
# f(1) -> 1
# f(2) -> 1
# f(3) -> 2
# f(4) -> 3
...
# f(10) -> 55
...
```

Now the reason I've added the Lambda Calculus tag is because I'm not sure if this question falls under the domain of simply understanding how Python handles this. I've read a tiny bit about the Y combinator in lambda calculus, but that's a foreign language to me and couldn't derive anything from resources I found for this about lambda calculus.

Now, the reason I'm trying to do this in one line of code, as opposed to naming it, is because I want to try and put this lambda function into list comprehension. So do something like this:

```
[(lambda f: f if f<2 else (f-1)+(f-2))(n) for n in range(10)]
```

and create an array of the first x numbers in the fibonacci sequence.

What I'm looking for is a method of doing this whole thing in one expression, and should this fall under the domain of Lambda calculus, which I believe it does, for someone to explain how this would work.

Feel free to offer an answer in JavaScript, C#, or other C-like languages that support Lambda functions.

**EDIT:** I've found the solution to what I was attempting to do:

```
[(lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v)))(lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v))))(lambda f:(lambda n: n if n<2 else f(n-1)+f(n-2)))(y) for y in range(10)]
```

I know that this is not at all practical and this method should never be used, but I was concerned with CAN I do this as opposed to SHOULD I ever do this.

Comment: What's a ballpark estimate of the largest `x` you would use this for?  10?  100?  1000?  1,000,000?

Comment: I don't particularly care about the efficiency of it. If it dies at 10, that's fine. I just want a way to do it without naming the lambda.

Comment: You can use [Chelsea Voss's Onelinerizer](https://github.com/csvoss/onelinerizer) to turn whole Python programs into one-liners. Print the first 10 Fibonacci numbers in Python 2: `(lambda __g, __print: [(__print([fib(x) for __g['x'] in range(10)]), None)[1] for __g['fib'], fib.__name__ in [(lambda n: (lambda __l: [(1 if (__l['n'] < 2) else (fib((__l['n'] - 1)) + fib((__l['n'] - 2)))) for __l['n'] in [(n)]][0])({}), 'fib')]][0])(globals(), __import__('__builtin__').__dict__['print'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
(lambda f: (4 << f * (3 + f)) // ((4 << 2 * f) - (2 << f) - 1) & ((2 << f) - 1))(n)
```

It doesn't start the sequence in the usual way:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, ...
```

But once you get past 1, you're fine.  You'll find a detailed explanation in the blog entry [An integer formula for Fibonacci numbers](https://paulhankin.github.io/Fibonacci/) along with lots of related information.

On my system, @lehiester's golden ratio based solution goes off the rails at F71, producing 308061521170130, instead of 308061521170129 and continues to deviate from there.

Comment: Best solution in my opinion.  +1

Comment: Nice solution ;)

Comment: Besides the fact that it doesn't handle 1 the way Fibonacci usually does, this is definitely the best solution. The rounding causes errors as your numbers increase and this doesn't have that issue.

Comment: @PaulHankin your blog entry was an amazing and enjoyable read, real treat, thank you! ("if you won't congratulate yourself, who will?!" a saying ;) )

Comment: @cdlane your answer doesn't say, which was the biggest correct Fibonacci number this approach is able to generate? If there's no limit to it, you should probably say so in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to assign your lambda to an actual variable, and then *call* the lambda inside the lambda:

```
>>> g = lambda f: f if f < 2 else g(f-1)+g(f-2)
>>> [g(n) for n in range(10)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: Will I **NEED** to do it like that? I had done it the exact same way before as well, but I wanted to find a way to drop that lambda function into the list comprehension itself. Which means there would need to be a way to do recursion with an unnamed lambda function. Which I don't know if that's possible - at least in Python.

Comment: @nixin72 From googling, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python) question, but the answer seems super messy and honestly goes against the whole point of a lambda

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was more interested in simply whether this was possible as opposed to whether in any given circumstance this would be practical in Python.

Answer (score 3):

I have a one-line solution that meets your criteria, but it is one of the most crazy codes I ever written. It doesn't use list comprehension, but it mixes dynamic solution and lambda function in one line.

```
fib = (lambda n: (lambda fib: fib(fib, [], n, None))(lambda fib, arr, i, _: arr if i == 0 else fib(fib, arr, i-1, arr.append(1) if len(arr) < 2 else arr.append(arr[-1]+arr[-2]))))
```

Just to explain it a bit. The first part `(lambda fib: fib(fib, [], n, None))` take a lambda function as parameter and then call it with the parameters it expect. This trick allows us to assign a name to the lambda function and to pass this name to itself.. this is the magic.

Instead second part, the core function, `lambda fib, arr, i, _: arr if i == 0 else fib(fib, arr, i-1, arr.append(1) if len(arr) < 2 else arr.append(arr[-1]+arr[-2])))` uses another trick to implement the dynamic solution. The first parameter `fib` is a reference to itself, the second parameter, `arr`, is the array containing our solution and it is filled from left to right calling recursively `fib` exactly `n` times. The recursion ends when the third parameter `i` becomes 0. The fourth parameter is an ugly trick: it is not used by the function, but it is used to call the append method of `arr`.

This is absolutely the less elegant solution, but it is also the fastest one. I report the timings for `N=500` below.

The naive solution is unfeasible, but here you can find the code to compute one element at a time of the series (this is probably what you wanted to mix lambda function and recursion):

```
(lambda n: ((lambda fib: fib(fib,n+1))(lambda fib, i: (1 if i <= 2 else fib(fib,i-2) + fib(fib,i-1)))))(N)
```

Solution proposed by @cdlane:

```
%timeit [0, 1] + [(4<<n*(3+n)) // ((4<<2*n)-(2<<n)-1) & ((2<<n)-1) for n in range(N)][1:]
10 loops, best of 3: 88.3 ms per loop
```

Solution proposed by @lehiester:

```
%timeit [int(round((lambda n: ((1+5**0.5)**n-(1-5**0.5)**n)/(2**n*5**0.5))(x))) for x in range(N)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop
```

My ugly solution:

```
%timeit (lambda n: (lambda fib: fib(fib, [], n, None))(lambda fib, arr, i, _: arr if i == 0 else fib(fib, arr, i-1, arr.append(1) if len(arr) < 2 else arr.append(arr[-1]+arr[-2]))))(N)
1000 loops, best of 3: 434 us per loop
```

Another ugly and faster solution which doesn't use the recursion:

```
%timeit (lambda n: (lambda arr, fib_supp: [arr] +  [fib_supp(arr) for i in xrange(n)])([], (lambda arr: arr.append(1) if len(arr) < 2 else arr.append(arr[-1]+arr[-2])))[0])(N)
1000 loops, best of 3: 346 us per loop
```

UPDATE

Finally I found an elegant way to formulate the one-line function. The idea is always the same, but using the **setitem** method instead of the append. Some of the trick I used can be found at this [link](http://p-nand-q.com/python/lambda.html). This approach is just a bit slower, but at least is readable:

```
%timeit (lambda n: (lambda arr, fib_supp: any(fib_supp(i, arr) for i in xrange(2,n)) or arr)([1] * n, (lambda i, arr: arr.__setitem__(i,(arr[i-1]+arr[i-2])))))(N)
1000 loops, best of 3: 385 us per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

**lambda calculus via Python**

Since this is tagged with *lambda-calculus*, rather than write an answer that relies on clever tricks or language features that are specific to python, I'm only going to use simple lambdas

```
U = lambda f: f (f)

Y = U (lambda h: lambda f: f (lambda x: h (h) (f) (x)))

loop = Y (lambda recur: lambda acc: lambda a: lambda b: lambda n:
  acc if n == 0 else
    recur (acc + [a]) (a + b) (a) (n - 1))

fibonacci = loop ([]) (0) (1)

print (fibonacci (10))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Of course we used four *named* lambdas `U`, `Y`, `loop`, and `fibonacci` – because each lambda is a pure function, we can replace any reference to its name with its value

```
# in Y, replace U with its definition
Y = (lambda f: f (f)) (lambda h: lambda f: f (lambda x: h (h) (f) (x)))
```

```
# in loop, replace Y with its definition
loop = (lambda f: f (f)) (lambda h: lambda f: f (lambda x: h (h) (f) (x))) (lambda recur: lambda acc: lambda a: lambda b: lambda n:
  acc if n == 0 else
    recur (acc + [a]) (a + b) (a) (n - 1))
```

```
# in fibonacci, replace loop with its definition
fibonacci = (lambda f: f (f)) (lambda h: lambda f: f (lambda x: h (h) (f) (x))) (lambda recur: lambda acc: lambda a: lambda b: lambda n:
  acc if n == 0 else
    recur (acc + [a]) (a + b) (a) (n - 1)) ([]) (0) (1)
```

`fibonacci` is now a single, pure expression – we could call the lambda directly in the `print` statement...

```
# in print, replace fibonacci with its definition
print ((lambda f: f (f)) (lambda h: lambda f: f (lambda x: h (h) (f) (x))) (lambda recur: lambda acc: lambda a: lambda b: lambda n:
  acc if n == 0 else
    recur (acc + [a]) (a + b) (a) (n - 1)) ([]) (0) (1) (10))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

---

**once again, using another program**

I wrote a very [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39550022/633183) (also in Python) but in the context of a different program – it might be useful to help see the *generality* of the techniques

---

**once again, in another language**

We'll do the entire thing again only this time in JavaScript. JS is better suited for *the demonstration* this exercise because we can show the code working here in the browser and the lambda syntax is much more permissive (in terms of code formatting) – other than that, you'll notice the programs are almost identical

```js
const U = f =>
  f (f)

const Y =
  U (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x)))

const loop = Y (recur => acc => a => b => n =>
  n === 0
    ? acc
    : recur (acc.concat ([a])) (a + b) (a) (n - 1))

const fibonacci =
  loop ([]) (0) (1)

console.log (fibonacci (10))
// [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

```js
// in Y, replace U with its definition
Y = (f => f (f)) (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x)))
```

```js
// in loop, replace Y with its definition
loop = (f => f (f)) (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x))) (recur => acc => a => b => n =>
  n === 0
    ? acc
    : recur (acc.concat ([a])) (a + b) (a) (n - 1))
```

```js
// in fibonacci, replace loop with its definition
fibonacci = (f => f (f)) (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x))) (recur => acc => a => b => n =>
  n === 0
    ? acc
    : recur (acc.concat ([a])) (a + b) (a) (n - 1)) ([]) (0) (1)
```

`fibonacci` is now a single, pure expression – we could call the lambda directly in the `console.log` statement...

> oh and it's *really* fast, too

```js
console.time ('fibonacci (500)')
console.log ((f => f (f)) (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x))) (recur => acc => a => b => n =>
  n === 0
    ? acc
    : recur (acc.concat ([a])) (a + b) (a) (n - 1)) ([]) (0) (1) (500))
console.timeEnd ('fibonacci (500)')
// [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ... 490 more items ]
// fibonacci (500): 3 ms
```

---

**practice makes perfect**

The lambda calculus has been one of my [favourite areas of study](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+lambda+calculus). With just the Y-combinator alone, I've spent countless hours [exploring its beauty and sophistication](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+y+combinator). I hope you find these explorations helpful. If you have any other questions on the subject matter, don't be shy to ask ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow assign a name to it in order to use a recursive definition--otherwise a recursive lambda function is impossible in Python since it doesn't have any special reflexive keyword that refers to it.

As @TerryA mentioned, you could use the trick in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481755/8626917) in order to generate a sequence of `x` Fibonacci numbers in one statement with the recursive definition.

Or, you could use the [closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011), which would be much faster:

```
[int(round((lambda n: ((1+5**0.5)**n-(1-5**0.5)**n)/(2**n*5**0.5))(x)))
 for x in range(10)]
```

This assumes that x is not very large, though, because the float arithmetic will overflow around `x=600` and will probably have large rounding errors before that point--as @cdlane points out, this starts diverging from the actual sequence at `x=71`, i.e. `x in range(72)`.

---

EDIT: @cdlane shared a closed form with only integer arithmetic, which should work for any `x` in theory.  I would probably use this one instead of the expression above.

```
[0, 1] + [(4<<n*(3+n)) // ((4<<2*n)-(2<<n)-1) & ((2<<n)-1)
          for n in range(10)][1:]
```

Comment: There's actually a response farther down in the post that does exactly what I'm looking for! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python#answer-10144992 I know that this method is not remotely practical, but I was more interested in a CAN I do this as opposed to SHOULD I do this. But your response meets the criteria for what I was asking! It's a single expression that outputs the correct result, so I'll accept that answer!

Comment: I'd like to see a recursive lambda expression that caches and refers to previously calculated numbers in the sequence so that it runs in linear time instead of factorial, but judging by that post, I am a complete novice with lambda expressions.

Comment: Would that even be possible with never instantiating anything as a variable? I know nothing about theoretical Computer Science, my school is VERY technical. So this is all very confusing to me. I'm going to sit down tomorrow and break down this whole thing and at least see if I can understand what's even going on in the responses on that question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @lehiester the answer in my post uses ordinary lambdas and runs in linear time