# How to bind a function to an object?

Tags: python, class, methods, bind

Consider this code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def some_method(self):
        def returned_method(self, new_i):
            self.i = new_i
        return returned_method

some_obj = SomeClass(5)
some_obj.some_method()(6)
print(some_obj.i)
```

It [ends with an exception](https://ideone.com/MVZ1Rr):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: returned_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_i'
```

Clearly, the method returned by `some_method` is unbound. It doesn't get `some_obj` as its first argument.

How to bind `returned_method` in `some_method` to `self`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`returned_method` *isn't* a method; it's an ordinary function. There's no need to declare it as taking two arguments.

```
def some_method(self):
    def _(new_i):
        self.i = new_i
    return _
```

`_` (no need to give it any particular name) doesn't need `self` as an argument, because it's a closure over the argument passed to `some_method`.

It gets used the same way as before:

```
some_obj = SomeClass(5)
some_obj.some_method()(6)
print(some_obj.i)
```

Comment: Ugh I guess I got distracted by JS, where I'd type `return _.bind(this)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Python does have a way to do this, but it's [not really documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType)...

Basically, `MethodType()`, from the built-in `types` module, works like JavaScript's `.bind()` function. It takes two arguments, the first being the function, the second being what you bind it to as `self`.

So for example, the way I used it is like this:

```py
from types import MethodType

class MyClass():
  title = "Thingy"
  
  def registerFunc(self, name, func):
    #Note: You have to use `setattr()` here instead of `self.name =`, because
    #"Python".
    #Note: Without `MethodType()`, just using `func`, it won't be bound with
    #`self` as the first parameter.
    setattr(self, name, MethodType(func, self))

#Now you can do this:
mc = MyClass()
def f(self):
  print("Works! " + self.title)
mc.registerFunc("test", f)

#Congratulations! You have just added an arbitrary, bound function to the class
#instance! Output: "Works! Thingy"
mc.test()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77629850/1599699