# Python - Use of Asterisk in a dictionary parameter for a reduce/lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the code below:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda d, i: (i[0] < 7 and d.__setitem__(*i[::-1]), d)[-1], [{}, *{1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}.items()])
```

The part that I don't understand is the *.

```
 [{}, *{1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}.items()]
```

returns:

```
[{}, (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Now if i run in isolation

```
*{1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}.items()
```

it returns an error : **"File "cell_name", line 4 SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here"**.  However I am able to run the code without * just fine as a one-line code and returns:

```
dict_items([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)])
```

I have googled it and in https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558 it seems related to unpacking containers, but this one is used in arrays.

However in the full lambda, the * seems necessary and throws an error **"'dict_items' object does not support indexing"** without the *.

Anyone understand this syntax jargon?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's being used in the same way as the article, it's just "extended iterable unpacking" which works in literals now

Comment: I don't know where you found that horrible one-liner, and I can respect your desire to understand it, but *please* don't actually use that piece of junk in your code. Throw it in the trash, where it belongs.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to have a multi-line lambda and I am trying to explore an answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233448/no-multiline-lambda-in-python-why-not

Comment: Don't. Just use a regular function.

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166505/5014455

Comment: I too second the recommendation not to use that awefuo one-liner. You don't *need* multiline lambdas. Just use a regular function definition. Quite frankly using a side effect in `reduce` seems designed to piss everyone off

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I just started python coming from C# background and we love our anonymous functions over collections but it seems i should not do that in Python.   I will look at the original question to understand this asterisk syntax.   Thanks Again.