# How do i write longer/complicated anonymous functions

Tags: python, function, lambda, anonymous-function

I have a python function that I can pass a function argument in 2 ways as shown below.

Lambda:

```
res = foo(lambda x: x+2)
```

Regular function passing:

```
def func1(x):
  return x + 2

res = foo(func1)
```

But I want to pass a slightly complex function to foo similar to the lambda function call. I can easily do this with LUA code.

LUA example:

```
res = foo(function (x) 
            local y = x * 2 
            if(y %2 == 0) then 
               return y 
            else 
               return y + 1
            end
          end)
```

How do I accomplish this with Python in a clean, programmer friendly way? All examples of lambda I see are for very minimal logic.

Comment: You lambda can reference a longer def defined unction.  Lambdas are expressions and there can only have one statement.

Comment: If you need a complex function, then pass a function - lambdas are intended to be one-liners, if it's something longer than that, then it's not an appropriate use for a lambda.

Comment: @ShpielMeister, I prefer to not define the function outside of the foo call.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, is there a way i can write similar to the LUA example i have given?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Multiline Lambda in Python: Why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233448/no-multiline-lambda-in-python-why-not)

Comment: @ShpielMeister Perfect. Thanks. As a python beginner, I wasn't sure what to ask or what to search for, so i ended up writing a new question.

Comment: @sgowd Nope, it's a different language, Python simply doesn't work like that. As I said: if it's more than one line, then you're not supposed to use a lambda in Python.

Comment: @ShpielMeister to be pedantic, a lambda cannot contain a statement, only an expression

Comment: Thanks @ÓscarLópez I was expecting python must be having an alternative to one liner lambda. I see now there isn't.