# How can I store a function in an array in python?

Tags: arrays, numpy, function, python-2.7

I am trying to to store a function in an array and store that array in a dictionary so I can later call values from that array through the dictionary.

I created a zeros array and created a loop that will store the function in the array as the loop goes on. Every cell in zeros array should contain the function but with different arguments depending on the loop.

I tried this:

Note, in the code, the function is "HeatedSolid" from a python package called SubKit which I imported as "sk"

Also note that the function does not produce an integer or float or any number its just a function that produces an argument that I will process using a different code.

Example:
if you pass arguments to the function,

sk.HeatedSolid(I put random put arguments here) returns the following argument:
<SubKit.build.Solid.HeatedSolid object at 0x2b407581b250>

```
matrix = some array

X_position = some array
Y_position = some array

matrix_dict = {
    10: {"multi": "69"},
    20: {"multi": "59"}, 
    30: {"multi": "49"}
}
array = np.zeros((10, 10))

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i,j] == "10":
            if matrix[i,j] in matrix_dict.keys():
                matrix_params = matrix_dict[matrix[i,j]]
                array[i][j]= sk.HeatedSolid(x=X_position[i][j],
                                            y=Y_position[i][j],
                                            symtype= 1,
                                            mult=rod_params("multi"),
                                            power=1)
print(array)
```

When I print the array its just a zeros array and the function is not store in the array

Comment: I don't know the return value for `sk.HeatedSolid`, but that's what you're storing in the array. So unless it returns a function, you're not storing any functions in the code you've provided.

Comment: `matrix[i,j]` should be `matrix[i][j]` ?

Comment: What this tagged [tag:python-2.7] by mistake?

Comment: `array` should be indexed as `array[i, j]`, though (if possible), a vectorized call to `sk.HeatedSolid` would be preferred.

Comment: `if matrix[i,j] == "10":` and `if matrix[i,j] in matrix_dict.keys():`, but the initial keys are integers, not strings; so you'll never get started into this nested if. (Aside: `if matrix[i,j] in matrix_dict:` is the standard way of checking for a key in a dict.)

Comment: What are you storing in `array`?   Functions, or floats that were produced by calling a function?  What's the dtype of `array`.?  of `matrix` (both bad variable names).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a function itself (a callable thing) in an array, you should use a python list rather than a numpy's ndarray (where the later can only store primitive int or float or string value).
In your case, you want to store function and its arguments, so you can do something like that:

```py
matrix_dict = {
    10: {"multi": "69"},
    20: {"multi": "59"}, 
    30: {"multi": "49"}
}

array = []  # note here
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    array_row = []  # note here
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i,j] == "10":
            if matrix[i,j] in matrix_dict.keys():
                matrix_params = matrix_dict[matrix[i,j]]
                array_row.append((sk.HeatedSolid, {"x":X_position[i][j],
                                                "y":Y_position[i][j],
                                                "symtype": 1,
                                                "mult":rod_params("multi"),
                                                "power":1}))  # note here, append a tuple of function and its args
    array.append(array_row)  # note here

# when you want to call it later
for arr in array:
    for (func, kwargs) in arr:
        func(**kwargs)
```

Comment: You could also store it in a lambda: `array[i][j] = lambda: sk.HeatedSolid(x=X_position[i][j], y=Y_position[i][j], symtype= 1, mult=rod_params("multi"), power=1)`, and call it directly: `for func in arr: func()`

Comment: @TedKleinBergman That's a great idea. But keep in mind that lambda in Python can only have one line (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233448/no-multiline-lambda-in-python-why-not). So it may have readability issues if too long.

Comment: @YuchengZhou The link seems to discuss multiline lambdas as in a lambda with multiple statements, not technically multiple lines. Almost every statement/expression in Python can only be one line unless you wrap it in parentheses, brackets, braces, etc. So a multiline lambda can be constructed by simply having the body in parentheses, like `a = lambda: (
123
+ 
321
)`

Comments strips the newlines, but imagine the numbers and `+` on separate lines.

Comment: putting the functions in an empty array is not a good option for me since I need to maintain the shape of the array for when I want to call it later.

I will try this lambda thing

Comment: lambda doesn't seem to work either 

[TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number]

its because of the zeros array it only accepts floats

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a normal zeros array I used this:

```
array = np.zeros_like(matrix, dtype=object)
```

I just to had define that the zeros array takes `object` since the function produces an object.

Comment: If this is the answer then you should delete your other "answer" (especially since that should have been an edit to your question, not posted as an answer).

Comment: Also, keep in mind this is really not what numpy arrays are meaning to be used for. A python list (which you can either start empty and append to or fill with `None`) is more appropriate.